# Compare attributes of objects inside a list?

Tags: python, list, object

I'm trying to sort a list of `textMessage` objects into several lists.
Each `textMessage` has three fields - the address of the sender, the time it was sent, and the body of the message.

I have `listOfContacts` which contains `Contact` objects.  Each `Contact` object has two fields - the `name` of the contact and a `listOfTexts` from that contact.  The `listOfTexts` is filled with a list of `textMessage` objects.

I'm having trouble with the function that does the sorting. Given a list of texts, I want it to add a new `Contact` object to `listOfContacts` if the contact isn't yet in the list.  Otherwise I want to append the `textMessage` object to the `listOfTexts` inside of the `Contact` inside of `listOfContacts`

I'm having a hard time seeing if the contact is already present inside of `listOfContacts`

```
def sortObjectArray(textArray):
    listOfContacts = []
    emptyList = []
    for text in TextArray:                    # For each text in the sorted array
        if text.address in listOfContacts.name:    # if the text's address is in list of contacts
            addText(text)                           # add the text to the list of texts in contact's class
        else:
            listOfContacts.append(Contact(text.get("address"), emptyList) #if address not in list of contacts, construct one with an empty list of texts.
```

I thought that `if text.address in listOfContacts.name` should check if any `Contact` with a `name` field of `n` exists in `listOfContacts`, where `n` is the sender of the text message.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: The first problem that you will likely encounter is that listOfContacts will not have a `name` attribute, since it is a list and not a `Contact` object

Comment: For the sake of clarity, lists and arrays are different things.  While CPython lists are array based (and I'd assume other implementations are as well), they aren't arrays (and Python doesn't have an array type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list object doesn't have the properties of the contained objects. Consider the following absolutely valid python list:

```
list_ = ["ah", 12, object(), lambda honey: str(honey) ]
```

and tell me why

```
if "ah" in list_.lower():
```

should have a defined behaviour.

What you want to do is make the objects in your list hashable by their names, and build a `set` out of them.

**EDIT**: hashable means you implement the `__hash__` function, which in this case might just be

```
class Contact(object):
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.name.__hash__
```

Also, you should define an `__eq__` function (eq like equality), so that python can check whether two contacts are equal:

```
    def __eq__(self,other):
         return self.name==other.name
```

As soon as you have done that, you can use the `set` type, which is just like the `list` type, but only allows a single "equal" object. That makes a lot of sense for a contact list! After having done that, you can just create a dummy Contact object and check whether it's in the set.

That, or you'll simply have to iterate over all of them:

```
if any(text.address == cont.name for contact in listOfContacts):
```

**EDIT**: that just checks if `any` of contacts has a `name` property that is equal to your `text.address`.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension inside of the generator expression.

Comment: @Dannnno: that's true, I'm removing it.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm rather new to python, what does making a list hashable mean? Is that the same as putting it into a dictionary? Also, could you please explain that line you wrote, I'm not sure I understand whats going on there.

Comment: @Tryer You don't want to make your list hashable.  You would want to make your `Contact` objects hashable.  This would mean implementing `__hash__` and `__eq__` in your `Contact`

Comment: @Tryer: edited. If something remains unclear, you might want to read python standard library documentation on sequence types.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. To clarify, the hash function would simply generate a unique identity for the contact, and __eq__ would tell python how to compare 2 objects in any statement that says `if object == object`. Is that how it works?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've decided to try using the second method you provided as it seems a bit simpler. is `if any(text.address == contact.name for contact in listOfContacts):
            contact.addText()` sufficient then? Once I know the contact exists I need to access an addText method in the Contact object, can I do it using the contact in your statement? Meanwhile I'm still figuring out the sets you mentioned earlier

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that you will likely encounter is that listOfContacts will not have a `name` attribute, since it is a list and not a `Contact` object. You can create a new list of contact names that will be used to check if the address exists already.

```
def sortObjectArray(textArray):
    listOfContacts = []
    contact_names = []
    ...
    for text in TextArray:                    # For each text in the sorted array
        if text.address in contact_names:    # if the text's address is in list of contacts
            ...
        else:
            contact_names.append(text.address)
            listOfContacts.append(Contact(text.get("address"), emptyList) #if address not in list of contacts, construct one with an empty list of texts.
```

Comment: If I used this method, how would I call the addText method that each contact object has since I'd be referring to a list of strings?