# How to identify when an attribute's attribute is being set? - Although attribute is a list of objects

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have seen this stack overflow question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330968/how-to-identify-when-an-attributes-attribute-is-being-set). And I want to do the same, however what if the mutable attribute is a list of objects instead of just an object? Would that solution work anyway? The problem is that when having a list sometimes I would like to do some computation when one object of the list has been changed or when all the objects on the list have been changed - The problem is that if all the objects are changed I **don't** want to repeat the calculation for each time an item of the list is being changed, because the calculation will be the same but it will be only valid when all the values of the list have changed.

For example,

I don't want this:

```
Set element[0] -> computation -> set element[1] -> computation ... -> set element[n-1] -> computation
```

I want this:

```
Set element[0] -> set element[1] -> set element[2] -> ... -> set element[n-1] -> computation
```

It is possible to do this? In the mean time I will try to play with code on the question attached, I will let you know if I have any update.

```
class Foomutable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutable = [Foomutable()]*4
        
    def computation(self):
        sum = 0.0
        for mut in self.mutable:
            sum += mut.attr0 * mut.attr1
        return sum

    
    @property
    def mutable(self):
        return self._mutable

    @mutable.setter # Set attributes of mutable
    def mutable(self, attrs):
        # mutable is the list of objects
        # Here if one or all the objects in mutable change the value of their attributes then
        # do computation.
        self.computation()
```

Currently the way of changing mutable is to loop for each element changing one or more of its attributes.

Comment: This feels like you want `element` to be a context manager, where the items are mutable while the context is open and the computation happens when the context is closed.  (This is basically how file handles work -- you can write lots of individual pieces of data into them while they're open, and the final "computation" of flushing the data to disk happens on close in order to avoid the overhead of a bunch of small writes.)

Comment: Yes @Samwise, I was thinking the same. I think it would be worth to have a flag. But I don't know if that would be in the mutable class or the monitor mutable class. The idea would be that when flag is True (or all flags in the mutable class???), then the parent do the computation, after computation the flag should be set to False again

Comment: I'm not sure what the "monitor mutable class" is -- it would probably help if you included an actual class definition and indicated how you want it to work!

Comment: Added a brief python code

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use the `mutable` property?  E.g. are you doing `Foo.mutable = [1, 2, 3, 4]` as implied by your code, or are you trying to do `Foo.mutable[0] = 1`, `Foo.mutable[1] = 2`, etc as implied by your question description?  For the latter I think `mutable` needs to return *another* object that implements the semantics you're looking for via `__setitem__`.

Comment: I am trying to do a for loop to change the attribute/attributs of each element. So I guess is the latter. Maybe that is what monitor mutable class does in the link that I attached right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is by having a context manager that grants access to the mutable object, and does the computation when the context exits.  Here's a simple example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import ContextManager, Iterator, List


class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._mutable = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        self._total = sum(self._mutable)

    def computation(self) -> None:
        self._total = sum(self._mutable)
        print(f"* new computed total: {self._total}")

    @property
    def mutable(self) -> ContextManager[List[int]]:
        @contextmanager
        def context() -> Iterator[List[int]]:
            old = self._mutable.copy()
            try:
                yield self._mutable
            finally:
                if old != self._mutable:
                    print(f"* changed {old} to {self._mutable}, recomputing!")
                    self.computation()
        return context()


foo = Foo()
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"Current attributes: {m}")
    # no computation happens because we didn't change anything
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"Now we're going to change them...")
    m[0] = 10
    m[1] = 10
    m[2] = 10
    m[3] = 10
    # recomputation happens here!
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"All done!  {m}")
```

Output:

```
Current attributes: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Now we're going to change them...
* changed [0, 1, 2, 3] to [10, 10, 10, 10], recomputing!
* new computed total: 40
All done!  [10, 10, 10, 10]
```

In this example I'm simply using a `List[int]` as the mutable object; you can apply this same general technique to any other mutable object, including a list of mutable objects, as long as you can correctly implement the comparison in the context manager that figures out if anything changed that requires a recomputation.

Here's an extended version of the same example using your `FooMutable` class.  Note that for the comparison to work, we need to implement `__eq__` on `FooMutable` objects, and we also need to make sure we're deep-copying the two lists (otherwise the "old" list just has references to the same mutable objects).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from typing import ContextManager, Iterator, List


class FooMutable:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return (
            isinstance(other, FooMutable)
            and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{'+'.join(map(str, self.__dict__.values()))}>"

    def copy(self) -> 'FooMutable':
        other = FooMutable()
        other.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
        return other


class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._mutable = [FooMutable() for _ in range(4)]
        self._total = 4

    def computation(self) -> None:
        self._total = sum(sum(m.__dict__.values()) for m in self._mutable)
        print(f"* new computed total: {self._total}")

    @property
    def mutable(self) -> ContextManager[List[FooMutable]]:
        @contextmanager
        def context() -> Iterator[List[FooMutable]]:
            old = [f.copy() for f in self._mutable]
            try:
                yield self._mutable
            finally:
                if old != self._mutable:
                    print(f"* changed {old} to {self._mutable}, recomputing!")
                    self.computation()
        return context()


foo = Foo()
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"Current attributes: {m}")
    # no computation happens because we didn't change anything
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"Now we're going to change them...")
    m[0].attr1 = 10
    m[1].attr1 = 10
    m[2].attr1 = 10
    m[3].attr1 = 10
    # recomputation happens here!
with foo.mutable as m:
    print(f"All done!  {m}")
```

Note that my implementation of `FooMutable` is mostly pass-throughs to its `__dict__`; if it's simply acting as a mutable container, it would be easier to make it a `TypedDict` or similar container where all these methods are already implemented.

Comment: interesting... I didn't know about context manager. However, as you said your example only works when changing the item by the same type. In other words, if I use objects I would need to change each item by an object, but will not work if I change the attributes of the object.

Comment: **you can apply this same general technique to any other mutable object, including a list of mutable objects, as long as you can correctly implement the comparison in the context manager that figures out if anything changed that requires a recomputation.**  All you have to do is make sure you're doing a deep comparison -- for a list of `Foomutables` I think all that requires is implementing `__eq__` on `Foomutable`.

Comment: another question maybe far ahead from the subject... Why the only way of accessing or printing the attributes and variables is using with foo.mutable as m? I am getting TypeError: '_GeneratorContextManager' object is not subscriptable if I don't do that

Comment: Because it's a context manager.  You have to use that `with` syntax in order to invoke the `context()` function (inside the `mutable` property) that will start tracking whether you've updated the mutable object; the `with` block is what determines when it checks for changes at the end.  If you were able to mutate the object outside of a `with` block, your `computation` wouldn't run.

Comment: I think `__eq__` needs to be implemented on both `Foomutable` and `Foo` classes right?

Comment: What problem are you encountering that you think implementing `Foo.__eq__` will solve?

Comment: Hmmm... the if statement on the context manager comparing lists of objects is not sufficient even if I implement `__eq__` on `Foomutable`, in other words it's not a deep comparison. I was checking this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335744/compare-attributes-of-objects-inside-a-list). But they talk about `__hash__` and also about `set`, I was thinking that maybe `__eq__` on Foo would make things easier.

Comment: The actual issue there is that in addition to implementing `==` the `old` list used for the comparison needs to be a deep copy (one of the hazards of having a list of mutable objects, you have to be careful about pointers).

Comment: Yes, and from what I have seen there are a lot of ways of comparing the objects on a list. What I am doing right now is: `if all(map(lambda x, y: x == y, old, self._mutable))`. And it seems to be working, but if there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: The code you wrote is exactly the same as `if old == self._mutable` (assuming you actually used `zip(old, self._mutable)` -- otherwise I don't think that code is even syntactically correct), but more complicated.  :)  It's subject to exactly the same requirements in terms of deep-copying `old` and implementing `__eq__` on the elements (`x` and `y`).  Better to just use the builtin list equality operator.

Comment: Last question... If attr0 and attr1 were objects, let's say that from the class Muty(). And instead of setting the object itself I set their attributes (int). Then the __eq__ comparison using dictionaries wouldn't work because the old and the new would have same object dictionaries - The object would be the same just with different attributes right?

Comment: `__eq__` would work fine as long as you implemented `__eq__` for `Muty`, **and** you would also have to make changes to `FooMutable.copy` to make sure it was doing a deep copy that included making deep copies of the `Muty` objects.  Every time you add another layer of mutability you have to think carefully about how copying these nested objects will work.  IMO mutable state should be avoided as much as possible and should not be nested, precisely because it makes you think about all of this stuff and opens you up to a lot of confusing bugs if you do it wrong.

Comment: In that sense, wouldn't be better to use copy.deepcopy function a more general solution instead of updating the dictionaries?

Comment: Don't forget to implement `__deepcopy__()` if you go that route!  Nothing works by magic.

Comment: The implementation of `__deepcopy__()` it is just needed in case you want to override and deep copy some things and not the entire object, I think. However, by default it should work right? Sorry for too many questions, I am just getting started with OO-Python.

Comment: If you're just getting started with Python IMO this is not a good starter project, because you're diving right into a lot of tricky stuff and I suspect you're also building some really bad habits in terms of design patterns.